# Angular 2: Submit a form data and accepts the value to another component/page

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I have a requirement to have a small form in the home page that consist firstname and lastname and when the user submits the form, it will navigate to a different page with another form(with more fields). the values inputted from the first form should be populated to the second form.

I am looking at shared service and using the @input.

Please let me know any advice and example approach on how I can accomplish my requirements. thanks!

Comment: Are you using template forms or data forms (formBuilder) ?

Comment: Not sure about that since I'm quite new with Angular2. but I am using input tags and just bind it to models using [(ngModel)] directives.

Answer (score 0):

You may use $stateParams to pass the data to other page.

See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

Comment: is this for angular 2? I don't like to pass on date through URL. I want the URL to be clean. I am thinking about shared service or sharing data within different component but not sure how I will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches depending if you use the router or not.

1. You can pass values by queryParams like this in your  tag:

`<a [routerLink]="['pathToNewFormPlaceholder']" [queryParams]="{'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Doe'}">Submit</a>`

where 'John' and 'Doe' are just placeholders for your [(ngModel)] values from the form and then subscribe to them in the new component:

```
 export class NewFormComponent  implements OnDestroy{
   params: {};
   subscription: Subscription;

   constructor(private router: Router) {
     this.subscription = router.routerState.queryParams.subscribe(
    (queryParams: any) => this.params = queryParams);
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
 }
```

2. Create a service `FormService`  with variable to store your data and methods:

   ```
   previousForm: any;

   saveValues(data) {
     this.previousForm = data;
   }

   getFormValues() {
      return this.previousForm;
   }
   ```

and add it to your providers in your bootstrap file like this:

```
    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
      FormService
    ]);
```

then in both form components provide your FormService in the constructor:
        `constructor(private formService: FormService);`

After you should call `this.formService.saveValues({firstName, lastName})` when you submit the first form.

To get the values in the new form component call your service and assign values to the desired fields.

```
ngOnInit() {
   let data = this.formService.getFormValues()
   this.firstName = data.firstName;
   this.lastName = data.lastName;

}
```

Comment: thanks! will try this after I finish my other task. I've moved on for while with this task.